# How to change text in cells (SpreadsheetView by ControlsFX)?

Tags: java, javafx, spreadsheet, controlsfx

I have the [SpreadsheetView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) class in my programm:

```
SpreadsheetView table;

gridBase = new GridBase(rowCount, columnCount);
ObservableList<ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell>> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (int row = 0; row < gridBase.getRowCount(); ++row) {
    final ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int column = 0; column < gridBase.getColumnCount(); ++column) {
        SpreadsheetCell cell = SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1, "value");
        list.add(cell);
    }
    rows.add(list);
}
gridBase.setRows(rows);

table = new SpreadsheetView(gridBase);
```

I can create cells:

```
SpreadsheetCell cell = SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1, "value");
```

but i can't rewrite text in this cells. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [the `setCellValue` method](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/Grid.html#setCellValue-int-int-java.lang.Object-):

```
// set item in 6th row and 8th column
gridBase.setCellValue(5, 7, "Hello World");
```